# How to make pushButton and lineEdit to connect and calculate in pushButton?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qlineedit, qpushbutton

since there isn't any useful How-To for beginners of PyQt5,

I'm stuck with a little problem       。

```
@pyqtSlot()
def on_pushButton_17_clicked(self):

    """
    Slot documentation goes here.
    """
    A=self.lineEdit_22.text()
    B=self.lineEdit_23.text()
    print(A + B)
```

Show 12 instead of 3（1+2=3）

I want to enter the number in the lineEdit inside the calculation by PushButton, and get the value.

Comment: [PyQt5 Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/).

Comment: print(float(A) +float(B))

Comment: @eyllanesc       It also works  thank you

Answer (score 1):

use float(A) and float(B) for the result

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning,
I get this is a string, not an Int type(1+2 = 12)

The point :  Convert string type to int

So the python syntax can solve this problem.(int)

```
def on_pushButton_17_clicked(self):
    """
    Slot documentation goes here.
    """
    A=self.lineEdit_22.text()
    B=self.lineEdit_23.text()
    A = int(A)
    B = int(B)
    print(A + B)
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.